# External scripts like AngularJs not been called on my popup Chrome Extension

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension, but I'm facing a problem. I'm trying to use AngularJs and bootstrap **only inside my popup**, but it did not recognize. The error I got is this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
```

Even with it on my dependecies inside the popup.html; When I look on Chrome what scripts were loaded, it shows me main.js and popup.js. But the angular, bootstrap and jquery scripts no.

I tried to add this to my manifest.json:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

And this to my popup.html:

```
<html ng-csp ng-app="app">
```

But still not working. I know that content scripts are isolated, but I didnt find any information related to popups in this context. Thanks for reading and here are my codes.

P.S.: Bootstrap CSS works fine, so the directories aren't the problem.

**popup.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-csp ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="mainController">
    <div ng-view></div>
    <h4>Choose your Destiny!</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" ng-click="kappa()">Kappa</button>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-secondary" ng-click="pride()">Pride</button>
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-success" ng-click="fon()">Fon</button>
    <scritp type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <scritp type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <scritp type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app', []);
}())
```

**manifest.js**

```
{
  "name": "Say It",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "__MSG_appDescription__",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/icon-16.png",
    "128": "images/icon-128.png"
  },
  "default_locale": "en",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "scripts/chromereload.js",
      "scripts/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "background",
    "bookmarks",
    "clipboardRead",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "contentSettings",
    "cookies",
    "*://*.google.com/",
    "debugger",
    "history",
    "idle",
    "management",
    "notifications",
    "pageCapture",
    "topSites",
    "storage",
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "scripts/contentscript.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": false
    }
  ],
  "omnibox": {
    "keyword": "OMNIBOX-KEYWORD"
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/icon-19.png",
      "38": "images/icon-38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Say It",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "images/icon-48.png"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Again, thank you for reading!

Comment: Consider using an IDE: the script tag is misspelled in your code.

Comment: Holy! Thank you man! @wOxxOm My bad here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @wOxxOm said. I misspelled the tag inside the html. My bad! Thanks for the help.

```
<scritp type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```